# Dealing with Exponent Numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I've been trying to get the mass of the mesh that my script is running on.  I've ended up with this code:

```
mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
exponentMeshVolume = mesh.bounds.size.x * mesh.bounds.size.y * mesh.bounds.size.z;
Debug.Log("Volume: " + exponentMeshVolume.ToString());
```

This gives me numbers such as:

```
Volume: 1.589856E-12
Volume: 1.201565E-11
Volume: 9.868388E-12
Volume: 6.849872E-12
```

However i've never dealt with exponent numbers before and I have no idea what to do with them.  My endgame is this: I want to play a different set of sounds depending on how big the mesh is, so the smaller ones get a 'dink' sound when it hits another object and the bigger ones get more of a thud.

Usually, I'd do a `switch` statement with like `case 3: break; case: 9: break;` to split them into different groups.  Is it possible to get the numbers down to a more managable int? On a similar note, how would I determine  the largest and the smallest within the one script, that is applied to all meshes in the scene?

Comment: they are just numbers, represented in a way that is practical.  so that firt one is 1.5whatever */ 10*12 (divided because its negative, 5E3 would be 5000 , so, in short  0.0000000000015whatever ....

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Log10.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply all the numbers by a trillion or so (to put them in a comfortable range) and then use an if statement.

```
double volume = exponentMeshVolume * 1000000000000.0;
if (volume < 5) {
  // maybe this is quiet
} else if (volume < 10) {
  // a bit louder
} else if (volume < 25) {
  // etc.
} else {
  // loud
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats just what I needed.  Except volume was mass not decibels! :D heh